# Число Фиббоначи. Массив

Tags: python, функции, числа-фибоначчи

Задание:

1. Удалить из массива все элементы, не являющиеся двузначными числами. (получилось)
2. Перед каждым простым элементом первого массива вставить сумму чисел Фибоначчи из второго массива (трабблы)

Код ниже:

```
import random
import math
from inspect import k

a = int(input("Введите число, которое будет началом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
b = int(input("Введите число, которое будет концом диапазона случайных чисел: "))
massiv = [random.randint(a, b) for a in range(10)] # Создаем и заполняем список, состоящий из случайных чисел и длиной 10 чисел
print("Сгенерированный список: ", massiv)
massiv_delite = [] #не двузначные числа, которые должны быть удалены. Массив нужен только для выполнения алгоритма
massiv_andelited = [] #обработанный массив с удаленными числами
massiv_for_Fibvonaci = [] #массив для числа Фиббоначи
massiv_finish = [] #массив для алгоритма IsPrime
for a in massiv:
    if 10 <= a <= 99:
        massiv_andelited.append(a)
    else: massiv_delite.append(a)
print('Задание 1', massiv_andelited)
for k in massiv_andelited:
    c = 1
    p = 0
    s = 0
    while c < k:
        s += c
        c, p = c + p, c
        massiv_for_Fibvonaci.append(s)
sum_Fibbonaci = sum(massiv_for_Fibvonaci)

for a in massiv:
    if (math.factorial(a-1)+1) % a!=0:
         massiv_finish.append(a)
    else:
        massiv_finish.append((sum_Fibbonaci,a))
print('Задание 2', massiv_finish)
```

Получается:

```
Введите число, которое будет началом диапазона случайных чисел: 1
Введите число, которое будет концом диапазона случайных чисел: 15
Сгенерированный список:  [1, 5, 5, 7, 6, 14, 7, 11, 12, 12]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Элина/Desktop/АГТУ/2 курс/ОАП/9.py", line 36, in <module>
    prime(massiv)
  File "C:/Users/Элина/Desktop/АГТУ/2 курс/ОАП/9.py", line 34, in prime
    massiv_finish.append(sum_Fibbonaci,n)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
Задание 1 [14, 11, 12, 12]
217
Задание 2 []
```

Полагаю, что проблема в функции. Как необходимо ее поправить/переписать? Не работает

П.С. Последней правкой исправила код на рабочий. Может, пригодится

Comment: Вы создаёте функцию, но не вызываете её.

Comment: @Krutoy4el прописала вот так (код поправила в вопросе), получилось только хуже... подскажите, проблема в самой функции или неверно вызвала?

Comment: Вы можете поточнее сформулировать свой вопрос, что значит "Не работает" ?

Comment: @Kromster не работала функция, не вызывалась или не видела список. Но, прошу прощения, переписала немного, убрала функцию, все получилось)

Comment: Спасибо))
Код в вопросе поправлю на верный

Comment: StackOverflow работает несколько иначе. Здесь размещаются конкретные вопросы и ответы, а не "верный код в вопросе" ;-)

Comment: почитейте про область видимости